# Page Inspector in Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Where is the "View in Page Inspector" menu item in Visual Studio 2015 RC. I have searched on the internet but could not find anything. Was it removed from new version of VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser connection in VS 2015 is the replacement of page inspector of VS 2013. Enable Browser Link Dashboard from the "Browser Link" button close to Run button. Then from connections, click on "View in Browser"

Comment: From "connections"?